# "spend a small fortune” vs “pay through the nose”

Tags: idioms

Are there any differences in the meaning of or when we use the idioms '*spend a small fortune*' and '*pay through the nose*'? The definitions in the Cambridge Dictionary are:

- a small fortune: a large amount of money
- pay through the nose: to pay too much money for something

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pay a small fortune (a large amount of money) for something, and that might (or might not) be the right or fair price for that thing:

> I pay a small fortune each month to live in Manhattan, but it's worth
> it for the view from my apartment.
>
> I paid a small fortune to put my son through college, and now he's a
> drug addict.

Paying through the nose means something different - paying *too much* for something:

> I paid through the nose to get my car repaired overnight. $2000 just
> to fix a broken window – can you believe it? (I could have got it done
> for $150 if I had waited until Monday).

The amount of money does not have to be large, just more than a normal sum - you might pay $20 for a hot dog at a baseball game that would cost much less somewhere else.